# Filters in the GET request

Tags: java, spring, get

What is the best way to implement filters in a GET request?

let's say there is a method that gets a user with an id equal to 1: `/user?id=1`

If you need to handle a lot of similar filters `/user? id=1&name=Sam&...` and not necessarily all will be used. What is the best way to implement processing?

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public String getUser(@RequestParam("name", required=false) String name) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the REST conventions, you don't add the identifier as a query parameter but as a path parameter. (`/users/1`)

Going back to having multiple query parameters, you have some options.

One is as you stated it, having multiple RequestParams with the required=false option.

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public String getUser(@RequestParam(required=false) String firstName,
                      @RequestParam(required=false) String lastName,
                      @RequestParam(required=false) String nickName,
                      @RequestParam(required=false) String mail,
                      @RequestParam(required=false) String sex) {
    // ...
}
```

Another option is using Java8 `Optional`.

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public String getUser(@RequestParam Optional<String> String firstName,
                      @RequestParam Optional<String> String lastName,
                      @RequestParam Optional<String> String nickName,
                      @RequestParam Optional<String> String mail,
                      @RequestParam Optional<String> String sex) {
    // ...
}
```

But all in all the best way if you have multiple search options is to transform the GET request to a POST request, passing all search options in a search object. You CAN pass a request body in a GET request, but it might be ignored by some libraries/servers so it's not recommended.

```
@PostMapping
public String getUser(@RequestBody UserSearchRequest searchRequest) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: And how to further process them in the method, since some parameters may be missing ? Writing a chain of if-s doesn't seem quite right to me.

Comment: If your query is intelligent enough you do not have to use a bunch of if statements. Other options may be JPA Criteria API if you have queries with lots of moving parts